# How can I compare key with a fixed number

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object like the following

```
 var items =
    {
        "k1": "value1",
        "k2": "value2",
        "k3": "value3"
    };
```

How can I compare key with a fixed number to get key and value of ("k2", value2) ?
Example: k1 = 9, k2 = 15, k3 = 23; fixed number (fix=12)

I will loop through all items to get only my key and value:

```
function(fix) {
  for(var key in items) {
     if (fix > k1 || fix <= k2) {
        document.write( key + " : " + items[key] + "<br />");
     }
  }
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: If you want people to start helping you, I would recommend you start _accepting answers to your questions_.  Click the green checkmark under the vote-down arrow on your other questions to accept them..

Comment: my expect is how to compare key, so that I can get my value ?

Comment: But you shouldn't just accept answers all willy nilly. [Here's some good information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I accepted already, sorry last time I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code i hope it will help you.I just edit your code and get value

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var items =
{
    "k1": 1,
    "k2": 2,
    "k3": 3,
    "k4": 4
};
    function testnew(fix) {

        for (var key in items) {
             if (parseInt(fix) >= parseInt(items[key]) && parseInt(fix) <= parseInt(items[key])) 
             {

                 alert(items[key]);
             }
         }
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="divtest" onclick="testnew(3);">test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Bryan please check your condition it satisfy both values.Thats why it execute for 4 times.Remove one condition then it run for that perticular condition

Comment: now i am using && operator instead of || operator and now i get 3

Answer (score 0):

Try you trying to do something like this?

```
var items =
    {
        "k1": "value1",
        "k2": "value2",
        "k3": "value3"
    };
function fix(value) {
return (items[value]) || "Not Found";
}

fix("k2"); // will return value2
```